# XAMPP: My localhost only listens to my Laravel file not to the other non-laravel file

Tags: laravel, xampp

I'm starting to learn the laravel framework. I can actually run my laravel project. But the other old project that are not using laravel framework doesn't want to show up when i search their URL. I'm thinking that when i installed my laravel it only listens to my laravel project only not the other project that's not developed using laravel.

Like for example:

*My web-based project.*(Non-laravel project)

when i hit the project link:

**localhost/projects/TutorialsVideo/MIMD-FINAL/free-white/white-archive/html/image_slider/index.php**

My browser doesn't want to show the project.

But when i tried to run my laravel project using this link:
localhost:8000

My laravel project shows.

How can i resolve this. Because i have multiple project files that are not using laravel framework but i still need those projects.

This was the error that i got when i tried to hit the link:

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: are your other projects inside xampp -> htdocs?

Comment: Yes, these projects are inside my htdocs folder.
I have multiple projects that are not using laravel. These project are contained in one parent folder named as TutorialVideos. I am hitting the right link for my old projects. It was working before. But when i installed the laravel framework, i dont know but it suddenly like this..

Comment: Did you make any VirtualHost change when you configured your laravel project?

Comment: The only thing that i changed when i installed my laravel httpd.conf & http-ssl.conf. From default of 80 i changed to 8080 and 443 to 4433.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Move the project you run into the htdocs folder and create and move the htdocs - project folder to the other project files. Change the folder name to htdocs for the project to run.